# Trying to "Save as PDF" the current page in on with CSS styles and data

Tags: javascript

I have a GridView where I can select a user and then the user's details and information gets populated on a form below. At the bottom of the form, I have a Print button that when pressed, will bring up the print dialog:

```
            <asp:Button ID="printButton" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClick="printButton_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg rounded-0 shadow-sm border border-dark-subtle border-top-0 border-1 p-3 col-6" />
```

Is there a way to open another tab with the page that I'm trying to save as PDF? I've tried this:

```
"window.open('URL_TO_POST','POPUP WINDOW TITLE HERE','width=650,height=800').print()"
```

where I replaced 'URL_TO_POST' with this link: "https://localhost:44357/ThisPage.aspx" which is the page that gets populated with user info. Unfortunately, the a new window opens up but does not contain the user's information. Is there something I'm missing with the script or is there another option for this? Apologies as I'm trying to learn JavaScript as I go. Thanks in advance and I hope you all have a good day.